# ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, utf

While trying below code then `error generate`.

I found many of same questions but still not solved it.

```
 <% product_prices = []
             product.product_prices.each{|product_price| product_prices << number_to_currency(product_price.price.to_f, :unit => "£").force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)}
          %>
```

Any buddy have `answer` or `trick`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert first to string before force encoding. Try code below:

```
<% product_prices = [] %>
<% product.product_prices.collect{|product_price| product_prices << number_to_currency(product_price.price.to_f, :unit => "£").to_s.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)} %>
```

Comment: did you try to change `.each` to `.collect` ? Did you separated each line with `<% %>`. I updated the code above.